# Argument in a proof for scalar maximum principle

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

I'm trying to understand how an assertion made in the proof of the scalar maximum principle follows from the compactness of the manifold we're working with. The situation is as follows:

> [image]
>
> [image]

I had an idea but I don't know if it pans out: we have that $u_{\varepsilon}(\cdot, 0) > c$ and that for some $(x_0, t_0)$, $u_{\varepsilon}(x_0, t_0) \leq c $. We can then define $t_1$ as the positive infimum over all such times, that is, define:

$$t_1 = \inf_{t \in [0, T)} \{\text{there exists $x \in M$ such that $u_{\varepsilon}(x, t) \leq c$} \}$$

By definition we have that $u_{\varepsilon}(\cdot, t) > c$ for any $t \in [0, t_1)$. Since $M$ is compact, we also know that $u_{\varepsilon}$ takes maximum and minimal values in $M \times [0, t_1]$. I think one can prove that there exists $x_1 \in M$ that satisfies what we want, but I don't know how to guarantee its existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $u_{\epsilon}>0$ at $t=0$, by the tube lemma and compactness of $M$ it follows that there exists a neighbourhood of type $M \times [0,\delta)$ on which $u_{\epsilon}>c$.

Following a similar idea, take $t_1:=\sup_{t \in [0,T)}\{t \mid \min_{x \in M} u_{\epsilon}(x,t)>c\}$. The above establishes that $t_1 >0$. It is clear that $\min_{x \in M} u_{\epsilon}(x,t_1)\geq c$. If $\min_{x \in M} u_{\epsilon}(x,t_1)$ were greater than $c$, then again by the tube lemma it would follow that $t_1$ is actually not the supremum of the set. Therefore, we have that $\min_{x \in M} u_{\epsilon}(x,t_1)=c$, and by compactness there is some $x_1$ such that $u(x_1,t_1)=c$.

Comment: Thanks! But could you state exactly what form of the tube lemma you're using?

Comment: @MatheusAndrade If $X$ is compact and $N$ is an open set containing a slice $X \times {y_0}$ of $X \times Y$, then there is a neighbourhood of the form $X \times V $ contained in $N$, where $V$ is a neighbourhood of $y_0$ in $Y$. We then use the fact that the set of points $(x,t)$ where $u_{\epsilon}(x,t)>c$ is open.

Comment: I've been thinking about it but I can't see how $\min u_{\varepsilon} ( \cdot, t_1) \geq c$, could you clarify that a little further?

Comment: @MatheusAndrade If it were $<c$, then pick $x_0$ the point which realizes the minimum. By continuity, $u(x,t)<c$ in a neighbourhood around $(x_0,t_1)$. Picking a basic neighbourhood $U \times (t_1-\epsilon, t_1+\epsilon)$ inside such a neighbourhood, we have that anyone in $(t_1-\epsilon, t_1)$ is still an upper bound for the set we are taking the $\sup$ of, contradicting the fact that $t_1$ is the sup.

Comment: I know I must be testing your patience by now, so sorry for that and thanks a lot... but how does it follow that anyone in $(t_1 - \epsilon, t_1)$ is still an upper bound? I know that any $t$ in there satisfies $\min u(\cdot, t) < c$ and so can't be in the set we're taking the $\sup$ of, but I don't see how it's an upper bound.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade Take $t_0 \in (t_1-\epsilon, t_1)$. Anyone in $(t_0, t_1]$ is not on the set by what I mentioned before. Since $t_1$ is greater than or equal to everyone in the set, anyone in $(t_1,\infty)$ is also not in the set. So the set is contained in $(-\infty, t_0]$, i.e., $t_0$ is an upper bound.

Comment: I see! I owe you a million thanks for your patience, I understand your whole answer now.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade No problem!